# Creating and filling array dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array which is to be filled using an object like this -

```
const std::map<Id, std::vector<Data>> *const DataSets[]=
{
    &object.data1,
    &object.data2,
    &object.data3,
    &object.data4
};
```

Condition here is, If **object.data1.size() == 0** I dont want to push it into array. in that case I want to fill my array like this -

```
const std::map<Id, std::vector<Data>> *const DataSets[]=
{
    &object.data2,
    &object.data3,
    &object.data4
};
```

**UPDATE**
I am using std::vector instead of array now and trying to initialize vector in same as array -

```
const std::vector<std::map<Id, std::vector<Data>>> *const DataSets
{
    &object.data1,
    &object.data2,
    &object.data3,
    &object.data4
};
```

I am getting error: E0146   too many initializer values. Can't I initialize my vector in this way? If not can anyone please suggest how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use `std::vector` instead, and push the items as needed?

Comment: thanks for reply @Some programmer dude since my further logic depends upon this arraya and the code is long back implemented...thatswhy not using vector.

Comment: Then there is simply no way to solve your problem. With a vector, and initializing it as soon as you have all the objects needed in in it, that's the only reasonable way to solve it in C++. If you do this in the global (or namespace) scope then another warning: Unless the objects are all defined in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) the pointers you have might not even be valid.

Comment: how it could be implemented if you do not know size.. also reading from vector is done in some way as from array...

Comment: Also remember that when you pass an array to a function, it naturally decays to a pointer to its first element. And you can [get such a pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) from a vector as well, if you need backward compatibility.

Comment: `std::vector` is exactly for *Creating and filling array dynamically* as the title says.

Comment: hi @Someprogrammerdude can you please suggest solution for above? I have updated the question

Comment: Now you have made the `DataSets` variable a pointer. It's the data *inside* the vector that should be pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do that.

Respectively you don't use C style plain arrays if you want to do anything dynamic. You just wrap it in yet another `std::vector` because that supports dynamic sizes.

Comment: next step in my code I have a function which takes this array as one of the parameter. I cant change previous implementation but need to send data as an array...

Comment: `std::vector::data()` and `std::vector::size()` are suitable for interfacing with that legacy interface.

Comment: hi @Ext3h can you please suggest solution for above? I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] since my further logic depends upon this arraya and the code is long
>   back implemented...thatswhy not using vector

Thats not a good reason for not using a vector. If you ever need a c-array you can still use `std::vector::data()` in combination with `std::vector::size()`. There is (almost) no good reason to prefer a c-array to a std::vector, even if you need c-arrays in some places.